# WooCommerce Image Sizes

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, image-size

My website had been fine until today I noticed that suddenly the sizes of product images on any page of the store have suddenly blown up to massive sizes. I haven't changed any code but I assume something has upset things. Previously 4 categories sat side by side correctly sized, now this has dropped to 2 images twice as large.

https://www.raymondmayjewellers.com/store/

Can anyone have a flick through and see what is causing this and how I go about correcting it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something has been amended on your website. To go back to the 4 categories side by side you need the following amendments:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:nth-child(2n), 
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:nth-child(2n) {
    /* float: right; */
    /* clear: none!important; */
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product, 
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
     width: 24%; /* was 48% */
     float: left;
     /* clear: both; */
     margin: 0 0 2.992em;
}
```

**Edit:**

Seems like removing the styles will not help. Try the below instead:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:nth-child(2n), 
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:nth-child(2n) {
    float: left; 
    clear: none!important; 
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product, 
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    width: 24%;
    margin: 0 0 2.992em 0.4875em;
    clear: none;
}
```

For the product page delete or comment the lines at

```
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images,
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images,
.woocommerce #content div.product div.summary,
.woocommerce div.product div.images,
.woocommerce div.product div.summary,
.woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images,
.woocommerce-page #content div.product div.summary,
.woocommerce-page div.product div.images,
.woocommerce-page div.product div.summary {
    /* DELETE ME */
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly to get me the correct sized images in categories and , but they're still only displaying 2 per row with a massive gap in the middle? 

And on product pages the main image is the full width of the area as opposed to around half the size of the space with the add to cart options to the right as they were before? 

I get the feeling this may have come from a plugin that was supposed to scale images to the correct size, which has now been deleted but seems to still be leaving a mess behind!

Comment: Please see the edit. Hope it will help you to sort out your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, we're definitely getting closer! For some reason now it is not consisntaly showing 4 images in a row but sometimes leaving gaps of which there seems to be no consistency?

Also in some instances a single product seems to be a few pixels lower in the row then others. I'm still clueless as to why this issue is happening in the first place!

Comment: The description of the product wraps onto two lines, that's why the gap appears below that product (use the following css to fix it `li:nth-child(5n) { clear: left; }`). I can't find single products with few pixels lower (link might help).